# How to preserve tabs in Vim when you paste something?

Tags: vim

When I paste any code into Vim, I the following happens.

[image]

How could I tell Vim not to screw up my tabs?

Answer (score 6):

Use `paste` mode, which is a special mode informing vim that you're going to paste text instead of typing it. 
Just type in:

```
:set paste
```

It's useful to have a mapping like:

```
:set pastetoggle=<F2>
```

to quickly switch between paste and regular mode.

Also you might want to consider pasting from clipboard using just <kbd>p</kbd>, if your vim supports `*` and/or `+` registers. In that case use:

```
"+p
```

to paste from clipboard, it'll keep indentation.

Note: it's sometimes useful to have this in your vimrc:

```
" better yank to clipboard
if has('clipboard')
  if has('unnamedplus')  " When possible use + register for copy-paste
    set clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus
  else         " On mac and Windows, use * register for copy-paste
    set clipboard=unnamed
  endif
endif
```

BTW, I just yanked it from my vimrc using <kbd>y</kbd>, and pasted it here with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, so it saves you some work ;)

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Alas this doesn't answer question asked, nor does the linked question. This stops auto-indent, but tabs are not preserved as required.